# Search all active sheets for string with offset

Tags: excel, vba

Totally new to vba but I have searched all the answers and not found something to help me.

I need to type in a cell call it (search cell) `"A1"` a word and excel try to match it through all active sheets except the once I type the word.

After match, must take the 6th cell on the right and copy it next to the (search cell) `"A2"`.

When we have a match the loop must stop searching.
Users can change the names of worksheets that's why I need to search all the active sheets.

Comment: You will want to look up `For each ws In Worksheets` loop and come back here when you have some code and problem to share. Right now you just have a task

Comment: Find it hard to believe you've not found anything, Research the Find method..

Comment: You will also want to research `Offset`. Between `Sheet Loop`, `Range.Find`, & `Offset` you should be able to get something started

Answer (score -4, accepted):

Here I assume the value to be found is in cell **A1** and the retrieved data will be placed in cell **B1**

```
Sub RetrieveStuff()
    Dim v As Variant, rDest As Range, Nm As String
    Dim sh As Worksheet

    With ActiveSheet
        v = .Range("A1").Value
        Set rDest = .Range("B1")
        Nm = .Name
    End With

    For Each sh In Sheets
        If sh.Name <> Nm Then
            Set rfound = sh.Cells.Find(what:=v, After:=sh.Cells(1, 1))
            If Not rfound Is Nothing Then
                rfound.Offset(0, 6).Copy rDest
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Next sh

End Sub
```

You may want to alert the user if the data cannot be found.